# IBM DB2 error in event viewer logs after IIS default Application pool recycle after 1740 minutes

Tags: c#, iis, db2, application-pool, db2-connect

I am getting a strange issue in one of my production servers which uses client IBM.data.DB2 version  to get data from DB2 database.This applications is designed in C# and deployed on  IIS-7.
All the transaction's work fine  **until the app pool recycle is requested after 1740 minutes.** This is a default IIS app pool settings.

The same code and settings in IIS are working fine on another server and no errors are logged even after app pool is recycled.

Order of events logged in Event viewer :

1. A worker process with process id of '968' serving application pool 'ASP .NET v2.0' has requested a recycle because the worker process reached its allowed processing time limit.
2. A process serving application pool 'Webservice WS' terminated unexpectedly. The process id was '2988'. The process exit code was '0x0'.
3. A process serving application pool 'ASP .NET v2.0' exceeded time limits during shut down. The process id was '968'.

4.A process serving application pool 'Webservice WS' terminated unexpectedly. The process id was '1456'. The process exit code was '0x0'.

5. Error logged in event viewer at the same time

> The description for **Event ID 4 from source DB2 cannot be found.**
>   Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your
>   local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or
>   repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> 2014-10-28-15.27.29.648000   Instance:DB2   Node:000
>   PID:6820(w3wp.exe)   TID:4340   Appid:none RAS/PD component 
>   pdDmpErrMsg Probe:20
>
> ADM14000E  DB2 is unable to open diagnostic log file 
>   "C:\ProgramData\IBM\DB2\DB2COPY1\DB2\db2diag.log".  Run the command
>   "db2diag 
>   -rc "0x840f0001"" to find out more.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `db2diag -rc "0x840f0001"` as suggested on the DB2 server you'll see, among other things, this:

```
Description:
    Access Denied

Associated information:
    Sqlcode -970
SQL0970N  The system attempted to write to a read-only file.
```

Apparently, the DB2 server cannot access its diagnostic log for writing. You'll need to talk to your DBA to sort things out. It's possible that the user account that runs the DB2 server has been changed, and the process now cannot access the log file, or may be some Windows software, like an antivirus or a backup program, locks the file.

Comment: The DB2 server does not have any problem . It is the client machine which makes connection to the DB2 server using .Net data provider.The IIS process on this machine crashes due to app pool failure . There is no log file existing on the server with the mentioned path in the error .

Comment: The DB2 client may also have a db2diag.log file, although it is typically not written to very much.  Check to see if the referenced location exists on your client.  @mustaccio's explanation would hold here, too, even if the problem was on the client side instead of the server side.  :-)

Comment: my prob got resolved by giving access rights on client server . i gave admin rights to the user-account trying to run the DB2 process and the problem did not appear again. Thanks to everyone for the inputs